# How do I use other js files in a service worker?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

How do I use other js files in a service worker? I don't know the right way to include my local js files into my service worker.

message handler in index.html

```
 <script src="pushjs\push.min.js"></script>
 <script src="pushjs\serviceWorker.min.js"></script>
```

```
messaging.onMessage(function (payload){
            console.log("new message: " +payload);
            //Push.create(payload.data.title);
             console.log(payload.data.title);
             console.log(payload.data.message);

              var notifTitle = payload.data.title;
              var notifMessage = payload.data.message;
              console.log(notifTitle);
              console.log(notifMessage);


                Push.create(notifTitle, {
                    body: notifMessage,
                });
             

          });
```

background message handler in firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
    console.log(payload);

                //Push.create(notifTitle, {
                //    body: notifMessage,
                //});
                // I would want to also use this here


     
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Two answers for you:

1. These days, in modern environments, I think you can make your service worker a *module* by including the options object in your call to [`register`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dom-serviceworkercontainer-register) with `type: "module"`, which means you can use`import`.

   ```
   import { something } from "./somewhere.js";
   ```
2. The global scope of a service worker is a [`ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) which implements [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope), which has an [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) function you can use to load scripts into the worker. Here's the example from that last link:

   ```
   self.importScripts('foo.js');
   self.importScripts('foo.js', 'bar.js', ...);
   ```

Comment: I have FCM service worker in public. I want to call asyn function that exported from firbase.js . Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In order to load a script into the SW scope, you need to use [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts):

```
importScripts('https://yourdomain.com/push.min.js');
```

Comment: I would add if you change any of these dependencies you will need to trigger the service worker to update because it will not just load the new versions. I need to double check, it may even need to be unregistered, but that may just me thinking about development.